# Method selector pointing at different object

Tags: objective-c, xcode, object, selector

The following method is in a viewController.

```
refreshTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(refreshLabels) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Is it possible to select a method inside appDelegate (or another class) at the selector instead of in the current object?

like:

```
AppDelegate *ad = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
refreshTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector([ad refreshLabels]) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

```
AppDelegate *ad = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
refreshTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:ad selector:@selector(refreshLabels) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

in your AppDelegate, there should be a declared refreshLabels method,

```
target
The object to which to send the message specified by aSelector when the timer fires. The target object is retained by the timer and released when the timer is invalidated.

aSelector
The message to send to target when the timer fires. The selector must correspond to a method that returns void and takes a single argument. The timer passes itself as the argument to this method.
```

the code in your question set 'self' as argument for target, but the method you are trying to call is in the AppDelegate

Comment: I can't believe I couldn't figured this out... Thank you!